# Encoding for open box character

Tags: input-encodings

Trying to include a source-file into my latex document using the listings package, i got problems with the open box character. Using,

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}
\lstset{
numbers=left,
numberstyle={\small},
literate={␣}{**WHAT DO I INPUT HERE?**}1}
\begin{document}
```

[image]

I couldn't find anywhere the encoding of the open box character. What is it ?

Comment: If you are referring to the visible space character, it sits in slot 32 of the ttfamily font, as in `\texttt{\char32}`..  By the way, please provide a complete minimum working example (that compiles) so that we can better assist you.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the visible space character, it sits in slot 32 of the `\ttfamily` font, as in `{\ttfamily\char32}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}
\lstset{
numbers=left,
numberstyle={\small},
literate={␣}{{\ttfamily\char32}}1}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
{
 Testing␣a␣visible␣space
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can use `\textvisiblespace`, as in `literate={␣}{\textvisiblespace}1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}
\lstset{
numbers=left,
numberstyle={\small},
literate={␣}{\textvisiblespace}1}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
{
 Testing␣a␣visible␣space
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]